# Registering models from another namespace with the Ember Data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a shared library that has internal Ember Data Models that are used by the calling application.  However, those `DS.Model` objects from the library don't find their way into the `store` for the calling application.

**library.js**

```
DS.SharedLibrary.User = DS.Model.extend({});
DS.SharedLibrary.BaseModel = DS.Model.extend({
    createdBy: DS.belongsTo('DS.SharedLibrary.User')
});
```

**app.js**

```
App.MyModel = DS.SharedLibrary.BaseModel.extend({
    customField: DS.attr()
});
```

However, when the adapter goes to resolve the `createdBy` relationship:

```
Error: No model was found for 'DS.SharedLibrary.BaseModel'
```

How can I inform my store of objects that exist in another namespace?

Comment: Can you provide a small example on jsbin? I would like to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your custom models by setting up an `Application.initializer` **inside the library**:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'myLibrary-models',

    initialize: function(container, application) {
        //one of these calls for each model you need to register
        application.register('model:DS.SharedLibrary.User', DS.SharedLibrary.User);
    }
});
```

Then your application's models can reference them like any other:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({ createdBy: DS.belongsTo('DS.SharedLibrary.User') });
```